# Concave function - Generic proof

Tags: functions, inequality, proof-writing, convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

For any concave function we have:

$$\frac{f(0)+f(x)}{2} \leq f\left(\frac{0+x}{2}\right) \Leftrightarrow$$
for any $f(0) \geq 0$, it follows: $$f(x) \leq 2f\left(\frac{x}{2} \right).$$
How can I prove this in more generic form, i.e.:
$$f(x) \leq 2f \left(\frac{x}{2} \right) \leq 3f\left(\frac{x}{3} \right) \leq \dots \leq Nf \left(\frac{x}{N} \right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is concave with $f(0) \ge 0$ and $0 < a \le b$ then
$$
 f(a) \ge \frac{b-a}{b-0} \, f(0) + \frac{a-0}{b-0} \, f(b) 
 \ge \frac{a}{b} \, f(b) \\
\Longrightarrow  \frac{f(a)}{a} \ge \frac{f(b)}{b}
$$
Setting $a = x/v$ and $ b = x/u$ gives
$$
 u \, f(\frac xu)  \le  v \, f(\frac xv)
$$
for $0 < u \le v$ and $x > 0$.

Comment: Sorry, how did you get the very 1st step: $$ f(a) \geq \frac{b-a}{b-0} f(0) + \frac {a-0} {b-0} f(b) \geq \frac{a}{b} f(b) $$

Comment: @Miroslav: Using  the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Definition)  of concavity on the interval $[0, b]$, with $\lambda = \frac ba$ so that the LHS becomes $f(a)$. Intuitively speaking: $(a, f(a))$ lies above the straight line from $(0, f(0))$ to $(b, f(b))$.